# Unzip user uploaded files through models in Django

Tags: python, django, zip

The user can upload zip file through models.py but I can not then unzip the file to iterate through the images and display them in my template.

## Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.conf import settings
from .validators import validate_file_extension

class Post(models.Model):
  title = models.CharField(max_length=140) 
  body = models.TextField(max_length=250)
  date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
  album_image = models.FileField(validators=[validate_file_extension])
  user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1) 

  def get_absolute_url(self):
     return reverse('photos:detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

  def __str__(self):
     return self.title
```

## views.py

Post create and index view works/ or at least worked until i changed from uploading a single image to uploading zip files and trying to iterate

```
class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name='photos/post.html'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)

def DetailView(request,pk=""):
    model = Post
    z = zipfile.ZipFile()   ### I am unsure of what goes here!!
    context = {
        "images": z,
        }
    template_name = 'photos/detail.html'
    return render(request,template_name,context)

class PostCreate(generic.CreateView):
    form = PostForm()
    model = Post
    fields = ['title','body','album_image']
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        username = form.cleaned_data['username']
        album_image = form.cleaned_data['album_image']
        instance.save()
        context = {
        "form": form,
        }
```

## detail.html

```
{% extends "homepage/header.html" %}
{% block content %}

{% for image in image%}

<img src ="{{image.url}}" style="width:304px;height:228px;">

{% endif%}
<h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
<h3>{{post.user}}</h3>
<h3>{{post.body}}</h3>
<h3>{{post.date}}</h3>
{% endblock %}
```

## post_form.html

```
<html>
<body>
{% if request.user.is_authenticated%}
<h3>Hello {{request.user.username}}, please upload your folder as a .zip file</h3>
{% endif %}
<div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-7">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-body">
                   {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
             <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                {{form.as_p}}
                            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
        {% else %}
        <p>You must be logged in to upload a file</p>
                {% endif %}
        </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

## post.html

```
{% extends "homepage/header.html" %}
{% block content %}

{%if object_list %}
<ul>
    {% for album in object_list %}
    <h3><a href = "{% url 'photos:detail' album.id %}">{{album.title}} - {{album.date}}</a></h3><br>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

{% else %}
    <h3>You have no photo albums!</h3>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd be careful with the zip contents and probably check on the filename/types in the loop here, but something like the following might work (untested). Basically extracts the contents assuming not in subfolders in the zip, then base64encodes them and uses that encoded version in the src specifying the data type.

```
# views.py  
import base64
import zipfile

def DetailView(request,pk=""):
    model = Post
    # z = zipfile.ZipFile()   ### I am unsure of what goes here!!
    mydoc = 'path_to_zip_file_here'
    # probably should do some logic on the name and file type
    # or be very aware of what is in the zip file
    with zipfile.ZipFile(mydoc, 'r') as z:
        for f in z.namelist():
            images.update({f: base64.b64encode(z.read(f)),})

    context = {
        "images": images,
        }
    template_name = 'photos/detail.html'
    return render(request,template_name,context)
```

and in detail.html:

```
{% for name, image in images.items %}
<img src ="data:image/jpeg;base64,{{ image }}" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
{% endfor%}
```

Comment: Sorry I am quite new to Django, how would you get the path to the zip file? Would it just be the path made in settings.py w.r.t MEDIA_URL? THank you for your help!

Comment: yes, probably. How are you handling the initial upload? How were you showing single images? It would be the same path I suspect.

Comment: Same IndexView class as above. And then the def DetailView above was originally class DetailView(generic.DetailView) and it only contained the model and template name and the detail.html was the same without the for loop and instead of <img src ="{{image.url}}" style="width:304px;height:228px;">, it had <img src ="{{post.album_image.url}}" style="width:304px;height:228px;">

Comment: why are you base64 encoding the uploaded files here? With django one saves the path of the uploaded file to the database instead of the file itself (which is exactly the way it should be)

Comment: @LukeCollins you are right, just use the post.album_image for the zipfile path.

Comment: @e4c5 I believe the question is how to view the contents of a zipped archive that has been uploaded. One way to do that would be to unzip on the fly and rebuild for the browser. Not saving the files in the database.

Comment: @LukeCollins I put a little project together at: https://github.com/junctionapps/so41267502 which might be of some interest. I'd probably never do it this way (uploading a zipped package of files) but if you have a good reason be careful with the content (as is the case for any content uploaded by users).

Comment: but what your code shows is an attempt to base64 images and save them to the DB

Comment: @e4c5 nope, just builds a dictionary (images) in the view to pass in the context to the template. If need be could save them out to the media folder, depending the requirements.

Comment: yes, looking closely at it again you are right, it doesn't save the images to the DB. but still base64 is wastefull

Comment: sorry, but is images variable undefined?

Comment: looks that way. needs a `images = dict()`